# can decode fbclid url of google analytics, where user comes from?

Tags: google-analytics

I have seen many times users comes from different fbclid URL to the site, I am trying to debug from where it comes from because I never share my URLs to facebook and I have seen very wrongs comments they spoil the website repo too, that the reasons I want to debug that.

Any helps appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean urls with fbcid parameters. You have never shared your links on Facebook yourself doesn’t mean they can’t be shared by other people. It is likely that these are sent by users via Facebook messenger app.

Comment: Thank for reply. Yes, I really want to know for which url fbcid is generated for ? Do you have any  idea about it

Comment: @RanjanDaswani I’m not sure what you mean. Any link shared on Facebook messenger app will have a fbcid parameter attached to it. In GA if you don’t have a filter to exclude parameter, you will see the path in your page report and if you drill down by source it should say Facebook.

Comment: Yes , Now I know fbclid parameter come from facebook only, but I actually want to know for which url it was shared. I only see the in GA is /?fbclid=<encrypted token>. Thanks

Comment: @RanjanDaswani If you can’t  see a path then it means the homepage was shared

Comment: Ahh! ..Yes .Thats possible because I can't see url. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Facebook shared url contains fbclid, if Your url show like "/?fbclid=." that means its url shared of home page of website, else with url with proper arguments like this  "article/xyz/34923/new/?fbclid=."